# How to find the max length unique rows from a dataframe with spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find the unique rows (based on id) that have the maximum length value in a Spark dataframe. Each Column has a value of string type.

The dataframe is like:

```scala
+-----+---+----+---+---+
|id | A | B  | C  | D  |
+-----+---+----+---+---+
|1 |toto|tata|titi|    |
|1 |toto|tata|titi|tutu|
|2 |bla |blo |   |     |
|3 |b   | c  |   |  d  |
|3 |b   | c  |  a |  d |
+-----+---+----+---+---+
```

The expectation is:

```
+-----+---+----+---+---+
|id | A | B  | C  | D  |
+-----+---+----+---+---+
|1 |toto|tata|titi|tutu|
|2 |bla |blo |   |     |
|3 |b   | c  |  a |  d |
+-----+---+----+---+---+
```

I can't figure how to do this using Spark easily...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This approach takes care of any addition/deletion of columns to the  `DataFrame`, without the need of code change.

It can be done by first finding length of all columns after concatenating (except the first column), then filter all other rows except the row with the maximum length.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val output = input.withColumn("rowLength", length(concat(input.columns.toList.drop(1).map(col): _*)))
  .withColumn("maxLength", max($"rowLength").over(Window.partitionBy($"id")))
  .filter($"rowLength" === $"maxLength")
  .drop("rowLength", "maxLength")
```

Comment: Thanks ! But in a case where there are two rows with the same id, it returns the two rows. How can I only choose one between the two (sort of a distinct on id at the end) ?

Comment: Maybe I've just have to dropDuplicates on id ! Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> df.show
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|   A|   B|   C|   D|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|toto|tata|titi|    |
|  1|toto|tata|titi|tutu|
|  2| bla| blo|    |    |
|  3|   b|   c|    |   d|
|  3|   b|   c|   a|   d|
+---+----+----+----+----+


scala> df.groupBy("id").agg(concat_ws("",collect_set(col("A"))).alias("A"),concat_ws("",collect_set(col("B"))).alias("B"),concat_ws("",collect_set(col("C"))).alias("C"),concat_ws("",collect_set(col("D"))).alias("D")).show
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|   A|   B|   C|   D|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|toto|tata|titi|tutu|
|  2| bla| blo|    |    |
|  3|   b|   c|   a|   d|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: More columns, then what?